# Can I compile Swift with Xcode < 6?

Tags: xcode, swift

I would like to try out Swift, but currently don't have an Apple developer
's account. Would it be possible to compile and run it without having Xcode 6?

Comment: And what about the $99/year fee?

Comment: @0x7fffffff  "Sign in with the Apple ID associated with your membership in the iOS Developer Program or Mac Developer Program to download and install the latest pre-release version of Xcode. "

Comment: @slanecek Sorry I stand corrected. I just tried and you're right. You can access the developer portal wit the free account, but you can't access anything that's still in beta without buying the iOS developer membership.

Comment: you can download it from some other sites ;)

Comment: > Would it be possible to compile and run it without having Xcode 6? Yes. Use a site like [swiftstub.com](http://swiftstub.com)

Comment: You can sign up for free for a Safari developer account. This should give you access to XCode 6 for free.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to https://developer.apple.com/swift/, the only current implementation is the XCode 6 Beta. The language documentation ([ebook](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) and [online](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5)) doesn't mention any alternatives.

<del>As far as I can tell, you have to be a *paid* member of an Apple Developer program to get the [XCode 6 Beta](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/):</del>

<del>"Sign in with the Apple ID associated with your membership in the iOS Developer Program or Mac Developer Program ..."</del>

**Update:** In a departure from past policy, Apple has made the XCode 6 beta available as a free download. See the new [Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/) for details, or [download directly](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_3_lpw27r/xcode_6_beta_3.dmg)!

Answer (score 3):

Wait for release of Xcode 6, which will be available in the Mac App Store. (I am not an authority to say this, but since Xcode 5 is available for free in Mac App Store, Xcode 6 should replace it once it's released)

Developing in Xcode 5 does not require paid developer account.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Version_history):

> Xcode 4.1 was made available for free on July 20, 2011 (the day of Mac OS X Lion's release) to all users of Mac OS X Lion on the Mac App Store

Annual fee of $99 or £79 will give access to beta releases and provides access to App Store to release your apps.